# Error when attempting to configure cmake for cross compilation to android

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I have been trying to build a c++ library for android using cmake cross compilation.
The library itself is a trivial test I made purely for testing the androind build process.
I have been using the cmake gui (v 3.25.0) on a windows machine.
I use a visual studio 2019 generator in cmake and specify a toolchain file.

Unfortunately, I seem to get the same error whatever I try. I tried searching for similar problems and trouble shooting, but have so far been unable to make any progress. If anyone with more experience could lend a hand, I would be very grateful!

I have attempted setting many different variables in the toolchain file in an attempt to resolve the problem, but the basic version of what I am working with is:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK64/android-ndk-r16b/)
```

The error I run into happens whenever I configure cmake. The outut I get from cmake looks something like this:

```
Android: Targeting API '27' with architecture 'arm', ABI 'armeabi-v7a', and processor 'armv7-a'
Android: Selected Clang toolchain 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang' with GCC toolchain 'arm-linux-androideabi-4.9'
The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.300080
The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.300080
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working C compiler: C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK64/android-ndk-r16b//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK64/android-ndk-r16b//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK64/android-ndk-r16b//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/username/Documents/Code Projects/Android Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-zqgcqm
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_b0f1d.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework

    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    

      ANDROID_HOME=C:\\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25

      ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3

      JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot

      NDK_ROOT=C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b

      testCCompiler.c

    clang.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '-mthumb' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\Users\username\Documents\Code Projects\Android Test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-zqgcqm\cmTC_b0f1d.vcxproj]

    clang.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\Users\username\Documents\Code Projects\Android Test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-zqgcqm\cmTC_b0f1d.vcxproj]

    clang.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '-mfloat-abi=softfp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] [C:\Users\username\Documents\Code Projects\Android Test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-zqgcqm\cmTC_b0f1d.vcxproj]

    CLANGCOMPILE : error : unknown target CPU 'armv7-a' [C:\Users\username\Documents\Code Projects\Android Test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-zqgcqm\cmTC_b0f1d.vcxproj]

    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I initially used used the NDK version found in the android tools for visual studio found at: "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK64/android-ndk-r16b/"
as an NDK version.

I have also tried directly downloading the latest version of the NDK and pointing to that with CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK in the toolchain file, though this did not seem to make any change.

I have tried directly using the toolchain.cmake files found at "NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"
for both the NDK versions described above. This too gave the same error.

Any ideas what could be causing this or how to fix?

Comment: First, the compiler version is Clang 5.0, it is ancient. You might want to update it and report back. Btw. Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 are released alredy.

Since the current compiler does not know a target named `armv7-a` the culprit might be `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI` It is either set incorrectly, or the given target is too new for the installed toolchain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out there were a few things I was misunderstanding about cross-compiling to android. Your comments helped nudge me towards getting things right. I have moved on from the dummy project here to something more complex, and am getting another error! This time when I use the setting that work for the simple project, I get:
"CLANGCOMPILE : error : invalid value 'c++17' in '-std=c++17'"
Ok, fair enough, the ndk and clang version are pretty old.

However, if I use a later ndk version, it fails, saying
"The C compiler identification is unknown"
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you update your question to show a full example CMakeLists.txt and the toolchain file?

Comment: Hey, I judged that my new problem was different enough to warrant a new post rather than ammend the original one too much. This is a link to it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74856757/20756692). Thanks for the help you have given sso far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was misunderstanding a few things about cross-compiling to android.

First, if I want to be able to use the static library (e.g in android studio), I will need to generate and build a solution for more than one android ABI.
The ABI's to build for are: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86_64, x86. I then need to check for each android ABI in the CMakeLists.txt file of Android studio (e.g. elseif(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL arm64-v8a)) and swap out the location of the library to import to the build folder of that particular ABI.

As far as I am aware, it is unfortunately not possible to generate for all these ABI's as seperate platforms within the same visual studio solution. Given that, cmake must be run 4 seperate times to different build folders, each time targeting a different ABI and generator platform. To save the hassle of doing this manually, creating a batch (.bat) script to automate the process seems the best way to go. This will involve using cmake from the command line instead of the GUI version. The script can also be made to build the generated projects to save opening each one in visual studio and building there.

The batch script I have made to generate and build cross-compilation projects for android is as follows:

```
@echo OFF
set BUILD_DIR=build
set ANDROID_NDK=C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r23c
set GENERATOR="Visual Studio 17 2022"

set CMAKE_GENERATOR=-G %GENERATOR%
set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%ANDROID_NDK%\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android

set EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS=-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static

CALL :build_android armeabi-v7a ARM 16
CALL :build_android arm64-v8a ARM64 21
CALL :build_android x86_64 x64 21
CALL :build_android x86 x86 16
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 



:build_android
set ABI_VERSION=%~1
set GENERATOR_PLATFORM=%~2
set MINIMUM_API_LEVEL=%~3
set CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=-DANDROID_ABI=%ABI_VERSION%
set ABI_BUILD_DIR=%BUILD_DIR%\%ABI_VERSION%
set CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=-A %GENERATOR_PLATFORM%
set CMAKE_BUILD_DIR=-B %ABI_BUILD_DIR%
set CMAKE_MIN_API=-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-%MINIMUM_API_LEVEL%

set CMAKE_ARGS=%CMAKE_BUILD_DIR% %CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI% %CMAKE_GENERATOR% %CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM% %CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME% %CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE% %CMAKE_MIN_API%

echo building for android ABI: %ABI_VERSION%
echo cmake arguments = %CMAKE_ARGS%
echo:

cmake %CMAKE_ARGS% %EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS%
echo:

cmake --build %ABI_BUILD_DIR% --target ALL_BUILD

echo:
echo:

EXIT /B 0
```

This worked for my simple test library, but I guess depending on the project the arguments to the cmake commands may need to be tweaked.