# Problems attempting to build oboe c++ library using cmake on windows

Tags: android, c++, batch-file, cmake, oboe

I am attempting to build 'oboe' on a windows machine using cmake (version 3.25.0) and a visual studio generator. The end goal is to create a c++ audio library that uses oboe as the back end for android, but as a first step simply geting oboe to build is the plan.

I have managed to succesfully generate build and use a static library with a few simple test functions using the method described below, but I run into errors when attempting to build oboe.

I have also managed to get oboe to build by using the method described in the documentation and
doing add_subdirectory etc. in the CMakeLists file of android studio. However I am trying to generate/ build using cmake outside of android studio.

The oboe repo is found here: https://github.com/google/oboe

The toolchain file I am using is: 'android.toolchain.cmake' included in the NDK at the location: ndk version/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake

I use a batch script to automate generating/ building to several different android ABI's, inspired by a similar shell script included with the oboe repo 'build_all_android.sh'. The .bat script I made is shown below:

```
@echo OFF
set BUILD_DIR=build
set ANDROID_NDK=C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r23c
set GENERATOR="Visual Studio 17 2022"

set CMAKE_GENERATOR=-G %GENERATOR%
set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%ANDROID_NDK%\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android

set EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS=-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static

CALL :build_android armeabi-v7a ARM 16
CALL :build_android arm64-v8a ARM64 21
CALL :build_android x86_64 x64 21
CALL :build_android x86 x86 16
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 



:build_android
set ABI_VERSION=%~1
set GENERATOR_PLATFORM=%~2
set MINIMUM_API_LEVEL=%~3
set CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=-DANDROID_ABI=%ABI_VERSION%
set ABI_BUILD_DIR=%BUILD_DIR%\%ABI_VERSION%
set CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=-A %GENERATOR_PLATFORM%
set CMAKE_BUILD_DIR=-B %ABI_BUILD_DIR%
set CMAKE_MIN_API=-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-%MINIMUM_API_LEVEL%

set CMAKE_ARGS=%CMAKE_BUILD_DIR% %CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI% %CMAKE_GENERATOR% %CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM% %CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME% %CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE% %CMAKE_MIN_API%

echo building for android ABI: %ABI_VERSION%
echo cmake arguments = %CMAKE_ARGS%
echo:

cmake %CMAKE_ARGS% %EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS%
echo:

cmake --build %ABI_BUILD_DIR% --target ALL_BUILD

echo:
echo:

EXIT /B 0
```

When I run this using the ANDROID_NDK variable (line 3) pointing to the root of the up to date ndk that comes with the visual studio 2022 android tools, I get an error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r23c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/user/Documents/Code Projects/oboe/build/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-pp2ibg

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_c21fb.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:m && MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET Framework
      ANDROID_HOME=C:\\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25
      ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25
      ANT_HOME=
      JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jdk8u302-b08
      NDK_ROOT=C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r23c
      testCCompiler.c
      In file included from <built-in>:349:
    <command line>(1,9): warning : '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined] [C:\Users\user\Documents\Code Projects\oboe\build\x86\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-pp2ibg\cmTC_c21fb.vcxproj]
      #define __ANDROID_API__ 1
              ^
      <built-in>(342,9): note: previous definition is here
      #define __ANDROID_API__ __ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION__
              ^
      1 warning generated.
      ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
      ld: error: unable to find library -llog
      ld: error: unable to find library -landroid
      ld: error: cannot open crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Android\3.0\Android.Common.targets(125,5): error MSB6006: "clang.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\user\Documents\Code Projects\oboe\build\x86\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-pp2ibg\cmTC_c21fb.vcxproj]

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

and cmake fails to generate the project. I can actually get this to generate correctly, but only if I set the android NDK version within the cross-compilation options of visual studio to use the NDK bundled with my installation of Android studio, and also set the ANDROID_NDK variable of the batch script to point to the same root.
In this case, though cmake generates the project the build fails with a similar reason to the warning given above:

```
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/user/Documents/Code Projects/oboe/CMakeLists.txt
  AAudioLoader.cpp
  In file included from <built-in>:404:
<command line>(1,9): error : '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Werror,-Wmacro-redefined] [C:\Users\user\Documents\Co
de Projects\oboe\build\x86\oboe.vcxproj]
  #define __ANDROID_API__ 16
          ^
  <built-in>(394,9): note: previous definition is here
  #define __ANDROID_API__ __ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION__
          ^
  1 error generated.
```

Thanks in advance for any help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Based on the description of your problem and the errors present here it seems to be an issue with system paths i.e.:  `ld: error: unable to find library -llog` `ld: error: unable to find library -landroid` the linker is being passed a compile flag to link specific libraries : liblog and libandroid and he can't find them. I recommend looking into what variables are set and if you can then update your environment with the appropriate variables. You could make your CMake file to print out the current environment variables and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your build fails because you instruct the compiler to view the warning `'__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined` as an error. And this warning seems to occur because Visual Studio still sets the macro `__ANDROID_API__` instead of setting `__ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION__`. I *think* that is a Visual Studio bug that was introduced when they started shipping the NDK 23 instead of 21.

**EDIT:**
This issue is being tracked [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-174-Android-warning-:-__/10254039?q=__ANDROID_API__%20macro%20redefined%20).